# Undefined result jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a script that send data to a particular `PHP` page and getting the result, after that the `jQuery` will check the result and distribute it.

The data is sent without any problem, and it is distributed fine. However whenever i want to print the distributed data in their rows I'm getting all the values as Undefined, and this is the code that i tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('textarea').css("resize", "none");    
     var recource = $('#recource').val().split("\n");
     var socks = $('#socks').val().split("\n");    
     $("button").click(function () {    
         for (i = 0; i < recource.length; i++) {    
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'ajax.php',
                 data: 'email=' + recource[i],
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data == "Hey, OK") {
                         $('#live').append('<br />' + recource[i]);
                     } else {
                         $('#die').append('<br />' + recource[i]);
                     }
                 }    
             });  
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: your return value is `data` not `recource` you should manipulate `data`. do console.log(data) to see what it looks like and there you can manipulate it

Comment: Please, take a look at [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call): _[...] **sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow** [...]_ . It might help you understand your problem.

Comment: I'm receiving my response successfully, however the data in the array is not displayed.

Comment: what did you get on console.log(data)

Comment: I'm getting that the value of (i) is always 3 it does not start from 0. also who did this question duplicated fix the code! i did not find any answer